# Count the number of individual days in a formatted column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, the first is a date column and the second references the first column cell next to and formats it as a day name.
I would now like to count how many Mondays, Tuesdays and so on are in the second column so it looks like the outlined box in the image. I have tried COUNTIF but that doesn't appear to work, presumably because the second column is a formatted value and not text.
How can I achieve what I'm after?
[Excel cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dewc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume the dates are in column "A" and weekdays in column "B"

for example, cells A1 and B1

If you are having trouble column "B" being number and just displaying it as "Tuesday",

try changing column "B" formula to below instead of changing format to "DDDD"

```
=TEXT(A1,"DDDD")
```

This will change Column "B" to a text, and countif function will work

Comment: Thank you Ralph and MutjayLee. MutjayLee's solution worked best for me with the existing data.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7). Just enter the following formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$10)=2,1,0))}
```

Here is an example to illustrate the above formula:

[image]

<sub>The above formula assumes (as illustrated in the sample GIF) that you have the range of dates in column A from row 1 through 10. For each weekday you will have to adjust the formula for the correct week-day number: Monday = 2, Tuesday = 3, etc. COUNTIF will **not** work.</sub>

Comment: Very nice visual presentation. Which software you used for getting this animated gif?

Comment: @skkakkar Thanks. It is a simple screen recorder creating an video file which gets converted afterwards to a GIF (Google search: screen recorder and then search for AVI to GIF).